# (Unity3D) Is it possible to call OnTrigerCollider2D() without binding any script to the Collider2D directly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I want to use a single script to control all elements of one scene. Let's call it "Director" script, bound to EventSystem.

I knew that I can get a GameObject by name or tag, and then manipulated the components such as transform. Thus I wondered if I can define the OnTrigerCollider2D() in this "Director” script without binding any script to the Collider2D GameObject, just like I define the value of the transform? If possible, how?

According to some friend, it is necessary to bind at least a basic script to the Collider2D to authorize the "Director" script to get access to the Collider2D event, no way to bypass this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)

> **MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D)**
>
> Sent when another object enters a trigger collider attached to **this
>   object** (2D physics only).
>
> Further information about the other collider is reported in the
>   Collider2D parameter passed during the call.

In order for the event to fire, the trigger collider must be attached to the same object as your behavior.  Using a small script on the object with the collider with a reference to call a method on your "Director" is the most common way I've seen this done.  As far as I know, it's impossible for objects to "subscribe" to collision events fired by other objects.

A poster [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/867859/how-to-detect-ontriggerenter-on-another-gameobject.html) suggests that one solution could be to create a collision manager that the "Director" checks, but the objects actually having collision events would need to notify the collision manager, so with that solution you're just adding a step.  Depending on what you actually want to do with collision events, it might make sense for you though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  You are right, a collision manager may solve the problem, but get notification from all colliders would be the next problem, and considering there may be hundreds small colliders in the scene, this would be a quite heavy process. Some person suggest that physics2d.spherecast and other physics cast may help to do the job. I will test these methods later.

Comment: Collider2D.OverlapCollider would do the job. Just hope it is not a very heavy process.